# Server works on localhost but not with ip on port 80

Tags: node.js, http, express, ip, localhost

I have this basic server and on one specific PC, if I visit http://localhost it works fine. But if I use its IP or try to connect from any other device using its IP, it doesn't work. I tried to run it on a couple of other PCs and it worked fine, I'm also sure it used to work in the past. So, I tried opening the port manually in the firewall for the inbound connections for port 80, but still, it doesn't work. I also did a test with port 3000, and this seemed to work. So it's something port related. I tried using netstat, to see if anything else was running on port 80, but I couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var webHttp = require('http').Server(app);
app.use(express.static('public'));
webHttp.listen(80)
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Here's an example to make it more clear.

I run the above server on a PC with local IP 192.168.1.104 on port 80.
If I try to access it from this URL http://localhost, it works fine. If I try to access it from the IP, http://192.168.1.104, it doesn't. Now, if I change the server port to 3000, both http://localhost:3000 and http://192.168.1.104:3000 work fine.

Comment: What if you type `http://192.168.1.104` or even `http://192.168.1.104:80`?

Comment: I tried both, but it doesn't work either, and this is specific to this PC. It works on other PCs

Comment: If it works fine on another PC, then it's just some configuration thing with that specific PC, nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I just asking if anyone had a similar issue and knows what may cause that. I just used this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) tool from MS to check if anything else runs on port 80, but it was clean.

Comment: Perhaps a Windows firewall on that computer blocking port 80 access except when using localhost?

Comment: Many thanks for your help jfriend00, I just found what was causing the conflict, it was Skype. I just got confused with tcpview tool, as I was expecting to show the port 80 like all the other apps, but it just displays as http.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it! It was skype running on the same port! I used this tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview to check everything that runs on port 80. My noob mistake was, that I was expecting to see port 80 appearing like all other ports (IP:Port), but it only appears as "http".

Comment: So, that doesn't explain why `http://localhost` works fine.  Something is amiss in your description of the problem.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't sound correct to me either, but I'm not anything close to an network expert to know why this works. I just double-checked and re-opened Skype and this broke again. I can screen record it if you want, but I'm pretty sure my description of the problem and the solution are fine.

Comment: Are there multiple network adapters in that computer?

Comment: Yeah, I have a LAN (which is not connected anywhere) and the Wireless (which is connected to the home router). I tried disabling the LAN adapter and running all the tests again, but it didn't affect anything.